# structural comparison of variants

Tags: compare, ocaml

I want to deal with limits on the integer number line.
I would like to have `Pervasives.compare` treat `RightInfinity` > `Point` *x* for all *x*, and the inverse for `LeftInfinity`.

In the `ocaml` REPL:

```
# type open_pt = LeftInfinity | Point of int | RightInfinity
  ;;
# List.sort Pervasives.compare [LeftInfinity; Point 0; Point 1; RightInfinity]
  ;;
- : open_pt list = [LeftInfinity; RightInfinity; Point 0; Point 1]
```

but

```
# type open_pt = LeftInfinity | Point of int | RightInfinity of unit
  ;;
# List.sort Pervasives.compare [LeftInfinity; Point 0; Point 1; RightInfinity ()]
  ;;
- : open_pt list = [LeftInfinity; Point 0; Point 1; RightInfinity ()]
```

["The perils of polymorphic compare"](https://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=node/33) says

> Variants are compared first by their tags, and then, if the tags are equal, descending recursively to the content.

Can one rely on any relationship between the order in which variants appear in a type declaration and the order of the tags?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should not rely on that. You should define your own comparison function. Of course, that means you'll have to lift it through datastructures (to be able to compare, say, lists of `open_pt`), but that's the safe thing to do when you want a domain-specific comparison function.

Note that extended standard libraries such as Batteries or Core provide auxiliary functions to lift comparisons through all common datastructures, to help you extend your domain-specific comparison to any type containing an `open_pt`.

Edit: Note that you *can* rely on that, as the ordering of non-constant constructors is [specified in the OCaml/C interface](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual033.html#htoc264). I don't think that's a good idea, though -- what if you need to put closures inside your functor argument type next time?

Comment: Yeah.  I know types should encapsulate their semantics, but I want to use this type as a parameter to another module that uses binary comparison operators in multiple senses and I don't want smallish change to turn into Yak-shaving.

Comment: Relying too much on the polymorphic comparison operators is one of the grave mistakes of idiomatic OCaml programming.

Comment: I claim the right to my idiomatic OCaml! ;-) But when using polymorphic comparison, I've never encountered a need to rely on the way in which tags are ordered, only on the totality (linearity) of the order. Perhaps in such cases the polymorphic operators don't come to mind.

Comment: @lukstafi: indeed, I think it's better to use Pervasives.compare only as a "I don't want to be bothered" way to get a total order for, say, unicity or tree-balancing purposes. I think starting to rely on the semantics of this comparison (eg. lexicographic or inverse-lexicographic for pairs?) is a rather dubious idea, on the contrary. But the first situation is also fragile with respect to evolution of the datatype (closures, objects, etc.).

Comment: @gasche, Yeah.  "The perils of polymorphic compare" which I linked to in the question argues that.  If the order of tags were known and manipulable, then one could craft ones types so that they compare well polymorphically.  Obviously that's not always feasible when eagerly canonicalizing is prohibitively expensive as with tree-based data structures like `Set.t`, but there are some types where it is possible, and useful.

Comment: @MikeSamuel: given your resilience to the reasonable (but sometimes more painful) ways, I edited my message with more information indicated that it is, indeed, possible to reason on the declaration order.